# SQL Server: Insert nvarchar values from one table into int column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables(Table A and B) with same column names and structure. Due to a requirement change I was asked to change datatype of one of the columns from nvarchar to int in table A. I've changed the datatype to int and lost all values as I used IsNumeric. Now, I'm trying to insert values from table B(nvarchar) into Table A(int) to replace all lost values based on matched ID's.

I've tried below, but getting conversion error:

```
insert into TableA([Percentage] )
    select CAST(Percentage]  as int)
    from TableB
    where  ID in (select ID] from TableA)`
```

My input values on tableB are like this :
Varchar:

```
0.1
0.05
1
0
```

But I want values like this in TableA(multiplied by 100):
Int:

```
10
5
100
0
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You want help with multiplication by 100?

Comment: `CAST(CAST([Percentage] AS NUMERIC) * 100 AS INT)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `update`, not `insert`?  In any case, that doesn't matter.  In SQL Server 2012+, you should use `try_convert()`.

I think you want:

```
update a
    set Percentage = floor(100 * try_convert(decimal(10, 4), b.Percentage) )
    from TableA a join
         TableB b
         on a.id = b.id;
```

Note that this first converts to a fixed-point decimal number and then converts that value to an integer.  A direct conversion of a string like `1.00` to an integer will result in an error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works. How can I do similar operation to convert nvarchar to decimal(14,4)?My input would be:6,565.00 
15,300.00 
4,375.00 
3,711.00  in nvarchar and output should be same in decimal(14,4)

Comment: I tried try_convert(decimal(14,4), a.fee). But my output is always: 0.0000

Comment: @user7617078 . . . Conversion to a decimal doesn't understand the commas.  You can convert using `money` or just use `replace()` to remove the commas.